Pastel Partner SDK Import Document Issue
I have a winforms application that integrates with Pastel Partner using the Pastel Partner SDK (PasSDK.dll).
When I try to import an invoice document (using SDK.ImportDocument(103, 1)), while Pastel Partner has the Process Customer function open, my application will go into a Not Responding state and eventually it will crash.  Notice the 103 in SDK.ImportDocument(), it will import the document into a batch for later processing.
In other words, a user logs on to Pastel Partner, clicks on View -> Open Batches, selects the open batch, which opens up the Process Customer function, while this Process Customer function is open, I am unable to call SDK.ImportDocument() from my application.
The SDK does not return an error code, it simply causes my application to go into a Not Responding state and it will not continue execution, and eventually it will crash.
My question is this - Is there some way to check if Pastel Partner has the Process Customer function open before I do a SDK.ImportDocument() call, so that I can skip the SDK.ImportDocument() call if the Process Customer function is open, and check again later until the Process Customer function is closed?
I am using Pastel Partner v18.2.1
